# main.js path auto inject wrong in webpack

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-router

when my url is 2 level localhost:8080/level1/leve2 is always show error that it can find main.js which is the file that auto inject by webpack.

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I prefer you share your webpack.config.js file or screenshot. Try to set the relative path of main.js in entry tag.

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: i found the solution. in my output config in webpack, i need to set public path to '/'